# My co-author mispelled my name while submitting an article to the Arxiv yesterday. How do I get this fixed?

Tags: paper-submission, authorship, arxiv, physics

My co-author submitted our paper to arxiv.org yesterday, and they mispelled my name. My name appears correct on the manuscript itself, but incorrectly spelled on the website.

I have claimed authorship using the paper password, and asked arxiv's help to fix this using the Help form. Will this be enough?

This is my first ever article, and my name got mispelled, so I am clearly feeling horrible.

Additional question to someone in High Energy Physics - An author page got automatically generated on InspireHEP too with my incorrect spelling, will that get updated too if arxiv fixes my name?

Answer (score 3):

Just re-submit a new version ASAP. You can change the authors, so you can have the correct name appear. Google scholar doesn't crawl arXiv on a daily basis, so if you resubmit today chances are that it will only ever find the version with the correct spelling. (Regarding InspireHEP, I cannot say.)

Comment: My co-authors are unwilling to resubmit, idk why. They seem to think that just asking the arxiv help will do, but even they aren't sure. They said that if that doesnt work, we'll resubmit with new revisions which will take time. This is why I am asking that is asking the mods at arxiv enough? I am junior to both my co-authors and so I do feel pushed around.

Comment: I assume that they will, but corresponding with the arXiv staff often takes very long (multiple weeks) as they are pretty overworked. By then, the wrong name may have appear in a lot of different places.

Comment: You could offer to do the resubmission yourself (which you can do after claiming authorship), then they don't have to do the work.

Comment: Maybe they dont want to create new versions without considerable change? idk why they wont resubmit. It shouldn't be so difficult right?

Comment: Maybe, you would need to ask them. But it actually happens quite often. I have had to immediately submit an update before, and I've seen it numerous times in the version history of other people's arXiv papers.

Comment: Thanks for the help, mate! I am panicking a lot less now. :)